# Python and R: how do you show a plot with Pyper in a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, r, jupyter, rpy2, pyper

I am creating a report using Jupyter. Most of my code is in Python, but I need to use some R functionalities.

I use a package called Pyper to call R in Python. It works well, but I could not figure out how to display a plot made in R (via Pyper) in the Jupiter notebook. Everything seems to work well, but Jupyter does not show the plot.

Here's my test code:

```
In [17]: from pyper import *
         r = R()
         r("library(TSA)")
         r("data(star)")
         r("periodogram(star)")
```

And this is the output from Jupyter (without the periodogram plot):

```
Out[17]: 'try({periodogram(star)})\n'
```

Comment: `pyper` and `rpy2` are completely different projects. With the latter, displaying a figure in a jupyter notebook can be as simple as putting you R code in a `%%R` block.

Comment: Thanks @Igautier, I now understand that pyper (in its current version) may not be able to display a plot in Jupyter as rpy2 does. So, after trying different solutions, I found a workaround, which I posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a workaround if anyone is using Pyper and wants to add a plot to Jupyter:

```
from pyper import *
r = R()
r("library(TSA)")
r("data(star)") 

# Save the figure
r("png('rplot.png');periodogram(star);dev.off()")


# Upload the figure to Jupyter
from IPython.display import Image
Image("rplot.png",width=600,height=400)
```